# previousSibling and nextSibling returns text?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Could someone clarify why the code below returns #text instead of 'li'
 ?

Shouldn't the next sibling of first li be li ?
Similarly previous sibling of last li be li ?

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <!-- comment -->
    <li id="A"></li>
    <li id="B"></li>
    <!-- comment -->
  </ul>

  <script>
    //cache selection of the ul
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

     //What is the nextSibling of the first li?
    console.log(ul.querySelector('#A').nextSibling.nodeName); //logs text

     //What is the previousSibling of the last li?
    console.log(ul.querySelector('#B').previousSibling.nodeName); //logs text
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling` for just elements.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The whitespace between the two is also a node. That's why JS libraries exist. To give you options like retrieving *element* siblings.

If the HTML source looked like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="A"></li><li id="B"></li>
</ul>
```

It would work as you expect it, because there's no whitespace between the `li` elements.

More recently, two more properties have been introduced, called  `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling`, which ignore that whitespace. It works from IE9 and up, with the other major browsers supporting it for a while now.

Comment: I'd suggest incorporating a mention of [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) and [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) into your answer, in order to complete it. And retrieving element siblings can be done entirely without use of any libraries using those methods, or via repeated calls to `previousSibling` (or `next...`) within a `while()` loop.

Comment: Support for the `xyzElementSibling` elements is excellent, even IE9 has it. IE8 doesn't, sadly, and isn't going away nearly as soon as we would all like. :-)

Comment: Yeah, IE8 has one foot in the grave!

Answer (score 2):

beter is use 'nextElementSibling' and 'previousElementSibling'